# Get caller of menuitem in global menu

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I am calling a class through a menuItem in GlobalToolsMenu. 
The caller of my args is always null altough it is called from a form.

Is there a way to transmit the form as caller?

Comment: What is the form that calls the menu item? Do you call the menu item by code?

Comment: The menu item is displayed in every form, because it is in the GlobalToolsMenu(Menu bar). It is not called by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are opening a menu item from `GlobalToolsMenu` it isn't associated with the current form, it works as if you are trying to open a menu item from an independent menu. If you need to get access from the called class to the current form you need to use some workaround.

E.g. you can try calling `WinAPI::getForegroundWindow()` from your class to retrieve a handle to the foreground window (the AX form with which the user is currently working). Having the handle, you need to find a corresponding `FormRun` object. For that purpose you can try customizing `\Classes\SysSetupFormRun\init` to keep a [map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa553382%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) with relations between form handles and the `FormRun` objects in `infolog.globalCache()`. Then you can use that cached map in your class to get the `FromRun` object from the retrieved handle.